# Linq query on large datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, enumerable

I have a 2 datatables which I have created a join. I can then copy this back to a new datatable. This is fine and works without issue. However, if I have a datatable with a larger number of columns, say 30 with various datatypes, how can I copy them all to a new datatable without specifying each column, i.e. similar to a SQL query ?
Thanks.

```
var results = from table1 in dt.AsEnumerable()
join table2 in names.AsEnumerable()
on table1.Field<int>("Id") equals table2.Field<int>("Id")
select new
{
    C1 = table1.Field<int>("Id"),
    C2 = table1.Field<int>("Col1"),
    C3 = table1.Field<int>("Col2"),
    C4 = table2.Field<String>("Name")
};

DataTable sout = dt.Clone();

sout.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

foreach (var v in results)
{
    sout.Rows.Add(v.C1,v.C2,v.C3,v.C4);
};
```

Comment: You must specify your resulting `DataRow`!

Answer (score 0):

First set primary keys for your tables.

```
dt.PrimaryKey = new[] {dt.Columns["Id"]};
names.PrimaryKey = new[] { names.Columns["Id"] };
```

Then, if you don't mind `dt` changing you can merge tables with the code,

```
dt.Merge(names,false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);
```

If you mind `clone` dt and do the same.